# How to set alignment of cells in Kendo grid after formatting it

Tags: telerik, kendo-grid, telerik-grid

I am using Kendo grid in my project.

I am using culture script for internationalization.

Using that script it formats the numbers in grid depending upon culture
I want to align the numbers to right, how can I achieve it?

[Here is a fiddle where I am formatting number column](http://dojo.telerik.com/ujiSE/12).

Answer (score 13):

You can achieve that using headerAttributes and Attributes property in the column description.

```
{
    field: "n",
    headerAttributes:{ style:"text-align:right"},
    attributes:{ class:"text-right" } ,
      //template: "<div style='text-align:right'>#= n #</div>",
    format: "{0:n}", type: "number"
  }
```

Please see the updated [fiddle here](http://dojo.telerik.com/ujiSE/17)

Comment: Worth a mention that class `text-right` is already defined in bootstrap.css, along with `text-left`, `text-center`, etc.